# PoS (Proof of Stake) what happens to the coin age of the change after I send an amount?

Tags: change, proof-of-stake

Ok simple scenario I have 100 'whatever' coins in a PoS wallet, they are mature and have a stake weight that is approaching the weight to stake and forge a block.
I send 1 whatever coin to my freind and get 99 back to the change address, is my stake weight consumed or maintained?

I realise using a fictional coin isnt ideal, if its treated differently in different existing coins that would be useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

Their age is reset.

You're creating a transaction with two outputs: sent amount and change. AFAIU, the age for staking is calculated from the confirmation height of the transaction that created them. Since each was newly created in the transaction, the age for both is reset.

Comment: Ok that is what I expected would happen, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, answer from Murch is correct. I would like to point some additional points which are probably usefull to know:

- Split your funds to ie. 1 block size (nr. of coins)
- Use coin control to choose manually which coins you would like to spend, if amounts are same, you would probably like to use the one with lowest maturity level.

As for your example, if you have 100 coins splitted as 1, then if you send 1 coin to your friend, your **99 coins would not loose on maturity as they are untouched**. This is a point which many do not do and so they loose their stakes quite often where other who know it profit on the same.

Beside that, if your 100 coins staked, then in most cases they will be split ie. by 50, where if you use only 1 of them to send your 1 coin, then only one would loose it's maturity level, not all coins.